# How we can zip text files via an integration service project?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ftp, ssis

I created a package in SSIS 2005. This package exports my tables from SQL Server 2005 to text files daily. I also created another package for uploading these text files to a FTP site. But the size of my text files is growing day by day. I have to zip them and after that upload them to the FTP. Any advice on how to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external script task in SSIS to call the command-line version of 7-zip (7zip.org). That will work to automatically zip your files.
Similarly you can use the same technique to upload your files with the windows built-in ftp.

Comment: Great. many thanks for you quick response. Do you have the query for zip and unzip files?